# Data lost at migration mssql server to mysql

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database-migration

I'm using Mysql Workbench to convert a sql server database to mysql. Everything's working fine, except that text fields are cut after a few words. The field type is varchar(8000). Any ideas how this could be solved? Thanks!

Edit: OK, I know what the problem is now: collation. Is there a way to migrate only data into an existing mysql-database?

Comment: Firstly, what version of mysql are you using, and secondly is there any particular reason you want to use such a large varchar instead of say a text

Comment: mysql version 5.5.27. No particular reason, I have not created the database, just want to convert it.

Comment: At what length is the field cut? What is the character set of the field?

Comment: Can you show the whole table definition please